# How old is Bloodraven aka Brynden Rivers when he meets Bran?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It is basically a fact that what Bran meets behind the wall is basically Brynden Rivers (aka Bloodraven) on some sort of life support machine that is a tree.

How old was he when this occured ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to *The World of Ice and Fire*, Brynden Rivers was born in 175 AC (after the Targaryan conquest), while the events in *A Dance with Dragons* take place the same year Joffrey died, 300 AC. So he was 125 years old at that point.

However, he was lost, and presumed dead, in 252 AC, at the age of 77; if we assume that he was hooked up to his "magical life support" shortly after that, it may also be accurate to claim he stopped getting older at 77.

Comment: For some reason I thought his birth year was unknown. I'm having one of those days i think. +1 good answer !

Comment: yeah I just got WoIaF still going through it page by page.